# ClamAV doesn't scan a file if the extension is JSON

Tags: python3, antivirus, clamav

I am using ClamAV with it's Python interface `pyclamd` to scan for any potential malware or "bad files" that are downloaded by the code on the server. While it scans all other files properly, the issue arises when the sample malicious signature is placed inside a JSON file and then the file is placed in a `.zip` folder. The file just passes through.
I can't include an actual malicious file since the company antivirus would remove it, however the sample malicious signature makes it easy to simulate malicious packages, so we use that.

Does ClamAV not scan JSON files?